Preload model in Flutter with google ml kit pose detection
I'm developing a Flutter app using the Google MLkit Pose Detection plugin
It works really well. Except for one weird thing that I just can't seem to solve.
The first time I call   poseDetector.processImage(someInputImage) It takes really long. About 20-30 seconds and at the end the app freezes for a bit. After this initial process image call everything is smooth sailing.
I have a workaround now where I create a simple dummy image InputImage.frombytes when the app starts. A provider keeps track of this operation and flips a bool when it's done waiting for the processImage.
I have no idea why this is. My guess is that the first time the app starts fresh, the model is downloaded from google (I'm guessing here). And after that is done it will load this model much quicker. I'm just a bit surprised that I can't seem to find a way to bundle the pose model with my assets. Or find a way to properly preload the model.
The UX in my app is terrible when opening the camera the first time the app is started.
Does anyone know why this is, and what i could do to make it smoother?
The pose detector is defined like this:
  final PoseDetector _poseDetector = PoseDetector(
    options: PoseDetectorOptions(
      mode: PoseDetectionMode.stream,
      model: PoseDetectionModel.base,
    ),
  );

And no matter how I create the inputImage for the first call to the processImage function this long delay happens.
I "warm up" the pose detector like this now:
  Future<void> _warmupPoseDetector() async {
    // Use a dummy image with dimensions and format that match what the detector expects
    const int width = 640;
    const int height = 480;
    const int bytesPerPixel = 4; 
    const int totalBytes = width * height * bytesPerPixel;
    
    final Uint8List bytes = Uint8List(totalBytes);

    final dummyImage = InputImage.fromBytes(
      bytes: bytes,
      metadata: InputImageMetadata(
        size: Size(width.toDouble(), height.toDouble()),
        rotation: InputImageRotation.rotation0deg,
        format: InputImageFormat.bgra8888,
        bytesPerRow: width * bytesPerPixel,
      ),
    );

    try {
      await _poseDetector.processImage(dummyImage);
      LogService.log('Pose detector model warmed up');
    } catch (e) {
      LogService.log('Error during pose detector warmup: $e', level: LogLevel.error);
    }
  }

But like I mentioned this takes just as long as if I would send a fram from the camera stream. The first call , after installing the app fresh, is always extremely slow and makes the app freeze a little bit.
EDIT ****
After digging abit in the ml kit code I found this:
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

/// A class to manage remote models.
class ModelManager {
  /// The method name to be called.
  final String method;

  /// The channel used to manage the remote model.
  final MethodChannel channel;

  /// Constructor to create an instance of [ModelManager].
  ModelManager({required this.channel, required this.method});

  /// Checks whether a model is downloaded or not.
  Future<bool> isModelDownloaded(String model) async {
    final result = await channel.invokeMethod(method, <String, dynamic>{
      'task': 'check',
      'model': model,
    });
    return result as bool;
  }

  /// Downloads a model.
  /// Returns true if model downloads successfully or model is already downloaded.
  /// On failing to download it throws an error.
  Future<bool> downloadModel(String model, {bool isWifiRequired = true}) async {
    final result = await channel.invokeMethod(method, <String, dynamic>{
      'task': 'download',
      'model': model,
      'wifi': isWifiRequired
    });
    return result.toString() == 'success';
  }

  /// Deletes a model.
  /// Returns true if model is deleted successfully or model is not present.
  Future<bool> deleteModel(String model) async {
    final result = await channel.invokeMethod(method, <String, dynamic>{
      'task': 'delete',
      'model': model,
    });
    return result.toString() == 'success';
  }
}

I'm not sure when this is called or how to call it programmatically. It seems it would be a good idea to ensure the model is downloaded before calling procoessImage. Also because you would need internet when starting the app. Maybe I will just have to use my workaround. But I would still love som input on this. Anyone that solved this before? Best would be to be able to bundle the model with the app, so it will work also the first run time.

The flutter plugin is not created by Google.  For the Java/Kotlin/iOS ML Kit SDK created by Google, there is no model downloading for this Pose feature.   If you really want to figure this out, you could try implementing with the Google-owned SDK and see if the issues still exist. This could help understand which layer it is from (the core logic itself or the Flutter wrapper).

This could be due to shader compilation jank. But it can't be 20-30 seconds. Did it has the same problem with release version?

No, this is not a shader jank. It is the same no matter if I use Impeller or not. it is downloading the tflite model the first time it's run. I'm now passing a dummy pic to the processImage on an isolate and wait for it to finish before allowing the camera to go online. Works ok, but I feel it's an ugly hack.
